# Can I create a table in Postgresql with all the days of the year as columns?

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a table in PostgreSQL that contains one column for the counties (column name: counties data type: varchar) in the state of Texas, and the rest of the columns correspond to each day of the year (from 01/01/21 to 12/31/21, the column names will be the actual dates, data type: date). Is there a way to create such table in a way that is fast and efficient?

This is an example of how it should look, (plus another 364 columns for dates).

| county | 01/01/21 |
| --- | --- |
| Anderson | 498 |
| Bexar | 89 |
| Kathy | 23,899 |

I'm fairly new to Postgresql, and I have been trying to look it up online without any success. I don't know if it's even possible.
Thank you!

Comment: That is NOT the right way to design a database.  How would you sum up all entries for June?  Instead, the columns should be "county", "date", and "value".  Now you're not limited to just 2021.

Comment: "*column names will be the actual dates, data type: date*" - no, that is not possible. Column names are just names, and not dynamic or computable.

Comment: Stop what you're doing and find a good book or tutorial on database design and normalization. The approach you described is **absolutely** the worst thing you could do. What do you do when you need another yea's data? What do you do when you need to query data based on a specific month or group of months (like a calendar quarter)? You also should find a good basic SQL tutorial or book, to understand defining and naming database tables and their columns.

Comment: This is not how to work with relational databases, like PostgreSQL. You can do it, sure, but you’ll end up with a ton of problems and issues. Do yourself a favor and don’t do it like this. Read something about data normalization and 3NF, and create a reliable and useful datamodel

Answer (score 1):

You should create a table like

```
CREATE TABLE data (
   country text NOT NULL,
   day date NOT NULL,
   value integer NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (country, day)
);
```

To make sure that users cannot enter arbitrary county names, it would be even better to have a separate table `countries`. Instead of the country name, store a foreign key to that table in `data`.